# mathematics expression gives wrong answer in java application

Tags: java, math

I created a simple program to calculate the volume of a sphere. 
But something wrong with the following code line

```
double volume=(4/3)*PI*radius*radius*radius;
```

producing the wrong answer.but if i change that to

```
double volume=PI*radius*radius*radius*4/3;
```

now it's giving the correct answer.

But both equations are perfectly alright according algebra. So why I get the wrong answer for the first equation?

Comment: A programming language is not math. There are many differences ("traps"). I recommend you read a book on the programming language (so Java in this case).

Comment: you should use casting for integer division, or change one operator to double - `4.0 / 3`

Answer (score 3):

`4/3` is interpreted as integer-division which means flooring - you have to explicitely state a floating-point division: `(double) 4/3` or `4.0/3`.

Comment: No, integer division does not mean rounding, but flooring. (`int x = 8/3; // x = 2`)

Comment: Not "may be interpreted." "Is interpreted."

Comment: Upvoted for further commentary help.

Answer (score 2):

`4/3 == 1`.  Integer division.

Try  `4.0/3` for float, or divide by 3 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It is because (4/3) is integer division and equals 1 by truncation. You should write:

```
double volume = (double) 4/3 *PI*radius*radius*radius;
```

or

```
double volume = 4.0/3 *PI*radius*radius*radius;
```